# What is IEnumerable in .NET?

Tags: .net, ienumerable

What is `IEnumerable` in .NET? What is the explanation?

Comment: To be honest, the definition on MSDN is very scary for a beginner, when all you want to do is a foreach.

Comment: Whilst I can understand why it was closed, I came to this from Google after MSDN wasn't that clear, and the answers have really helped me. If I could, I would vote for re open....This comes high up when Googling for "What is IEnumerable" and I am sure others have found it helpful.

Answer (score 81):

It's ... something... that you can loop over. That might be a `List` or an `Array` or (almost) anything else that supports a `foreach` loop. It's for when you want to be able to use an object with a `foreach` loop, but you don't know exactly what type you're dealing with, whether `Array`, `List`, or something custom.

So that's the first advantage there: if your methods accept an `IEnumerable` rather than an array or list they become more powerful because you can pass more different kinds of objects to them.

Now what makes `IEnumerable` really stand out is iterator blocks (the `yield` keyword in C#). Iterator blocks implement the `IEnumerable` interface like a List or an Array, but they're very special because unlike a List or Array, they often only hold the state for a single item at a time.  So if you want to loop over the lines in a very large file, for example, you can write an iterator block to handle the file input. Then you'll never have more than one line of the file in memory at a time, and if you finish the loop earlier (perhaps it was a search and you found what you needed) you might not need to read the whole file. Or if you're reading the results from a large SQL query you can limit your memory use to a single record.

Another feature is that this evaluation is *lazy*, so if you're doing complicated work to evaluate the enumerable as you read from it, that work doesn't happen until it's asked for. This is extra beneficial, because often (say, for searches again) you'll find you might not need to do the work at all.

**You can think of IEnumerable as if it were a just-in-time List.**

Comment: The key of `IEnumarable` is that the backing collection is `not enumerated` until specifically expanded, be it a foreach or accessor via an indexer. Unfortunately IEnumarable seems to be blindly used as the lowest interface which now causes problems with asynchronous data manipulation (e.g. executing SQL on GarbageCollected contexts). I would say that `ICollection` is every thing you said apart from the "lazy evaluation" and we should be using that, especially if the data has already been enumerated once!

Comment: Best simple explanation in plain English, hats-off!

Comment: I think IEnumerable is poorly named. Mathematically, and in computing, an enumerable is anything that maps to a countable set. So outside of .net an IObservable may be enumerable. In .NET IEnumerable is considered the dual opposite of IObservable in a pull vs push duality. The intention of IEnumerable seems to be what Java calls Iterable, which in my mind is a better name.

Answer (score 36):

It's an interface implemented by Collection types in .NET that provide the [Iterator pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternIterator.aspx). There also the generic version which is `IEnumerable<T>`.

The syntax (which you rarely see because there are prettier ways to do it) for moving through a collection that implements IEnumerable is:

```
IEnumerator enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator();

while(enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    object obj = enumerator.Current;
    // work with the object
}
```

Which is functionaly equivalent to:

```
foreach(object obj in collection)
{
    // work with the object
}
```

If the collection supports indexers, you could also iterate over it with the classic for loop method but the Iterator pattern provides some nice extras like the ability to add synchronization for threading.

Comment: Note, depending the syntax shown here is the C# 5 equivalent of a foreach. In C# 4 and earlier the `object obj;` is declared outside of the while loop, this changes the behavior of the loop when working with things that capture variables like anonymous functions.

Comment: tech-over-tech answer just brings up more confusion and frustration.

Answer (score 13):

First it is an interface.  The definition according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx) is

> Exposes the enumerator, which supports
>   a simple iteration over a non-generic
>   collection.

Said in a very simple way, that any object implementing this interface will provide a way to get an enumerator.  An enumerator is used with the `foreach` as one example.

A List implements the IEnumerable interface.

```
    // This is a collection that eventually we will use an Enumertor to loop through
    // rather than a typical index number if we used a for loop.
    List<string> dinosaurs = new List<string>();

    dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Mamenchisaurus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
    dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");

    Console.WriteLine();

    // HERE is where the Enumerator is gotten from the List<string> object
    foreach(string dinosaur in dinosaurs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
    }

    // You could do a 
    for(int i = 0; i < dinosaurs.Count; i++)
    {
        string dinosaur = dinosaurs[i];

        Console.WriteLine(dinosaur);
    }
```

The foreach looks cleaner.

Answer (score 7):

The short answer is that it's anything you can use a `foreach` on.

Comment: You can foreach over anything with a GetEnumerator method.  It doesn't have to support IEnumerable.

Comment: yeah, but most of the time `IEnumerable <==> foreach`

Comment: I guess no one actually knows exactly why do we use them , instead telling definition compare when and why should we use them

Answer (score 0):

- It is a base interface that enables us to loop or iterate over an Collection.
- The most important note about IEnumerable is that when you go through an object or 
  collection it just holds the state of a single item at a time.
- It has a good performance when you are iterating through big objects or collections 
  because it does not load the entire object to memory in order to make iteration. for 
  instance, suppose you decided to read a large file line by line and doing something on 
  that, therefore you can write your own [ReaderEnumrable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=netframework-4.8#examples) to read your file
  with high performance.
- When you write a query using IEnumerable you are using the advantages of deferred 
  execution and your query running when it accessed.
- Each time you run you iterate through a collection, a different
  collection created. For example in the following code each time the `listOfFiles` accessed the `ListOfAllFiles` execute again.

  ```
  public static void Main()
  {
      var listOfFiles = ListOfAllFiles();

      var filesCount = listOfFiles.Count();
      var filesAny = listOfFiles.Any();
      var fileIterate = listOfFiles.Select(x => x.FullName);
  }

  private static IEnumerable<FileInfo> ListOfAllFiles()
  {
      foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Environment.CurrentDirectory))
      {
          yield return new FileInfo(file);
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Most of your assumptions are characteristics of 'yield return' not specifically IEnumerable. IEnumerable is just interface providing a way for iteration, nothing else.

Comment: You are using `yield return`  when using `IEnumerable`, therefore they are completely correlated.